# a better way to implement pre/post conditions in rspec tests

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, metaprogramming, aop

It is all about OOP+AOP approach (familiar to me) and `rspec` approach (less familiar to me). Here is a code of my typical test. The code resides in each and every test file (there are many of those):

```
describe "Testing... " do

before(:each) do
  assert_no_application_errors
end

after(:each) do
  assert_no_application_errors
end

it "Test1" do
  begin
    ...
  rescue => e
    puts e, e.backtrace
    print_log
    raise
  end
end # it

...

end # describe
```

1. As you can see, the `before(:each)` and `after(:each)` are the same in each an every test file. So, the4 question is if I can write them in one single place that will be good for all the test files.
2. If N1 is possible - what will happen if in some file it will be necessary to apply additional steps in `before(:each)` or `after(:each)`? Will the new declaration replace or enhance the previous?
3. The `rescue` part is also the same in each and every test in the same file *and* in the other files. Which is the right way to place it in a single place as well?
4. Any other related advice on how to do the things right will be more than welcomed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want these assertions to be triggered for every test you have then you should configure a global "around" callback:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.around do
    assert_no_application_errors
  end
end
```

Just add this to your spec/spec_helper.rb and require in every of your spec files.

For more information about "around" hooks read this: http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/dir/hooks/around-hooks

Comment: thanks! I'll read that in brief, but need to understand one point ahead of reading: you say that the `rspec` (or any other framework) *does not need* to support the issue, raised above, just because of the simple reason: the language itself supports these aspects? Also, how about the collisions (say, if someone else adds some of the pre/post callbacks for a specific `it`)?

Comment: PS: also, should N3 and N4 be treated in the same way?

Comment: Just read the article. N1 and N2 of my questions are now perfectly answered. How about N3 and N4 please?

Comment: Why do you catch errors? I don't think you need to do that. If your code raises an exception then rspec will catch it and display a failure. You can pass '-b' option to rspec runner if you want to see the entire backtrace.

Comment: I am testing a web app (from the browser side). If an error happens, I want to know about it, to print some javascript-collected log _and_ to rethrow the exception. Does the approach seem logical to you?

Comment: Yep. Any kind of JavaScript-related error on the browser side, for example. OR, in general, if the selenium client code throws an exception, I want to catch it and to print some data, gathered on the browser side. Hope that I am explaining it all clear enough.